# Forcing a game to resize on launch?

Tags: screen, resolution, games

The good news: [this totally worked](https://askubuntu.com/questions/45042/force-full-screen-game-to-one-monitor) to give me screen size options for some games in Ubuntu.

The bad news: I didn't take into account the menu bar at the top of the screen, and the resized game doesn't allow me to move the screen up high enough to access the "OK" button at the bottom of the screen that would let me change the screen to an even more appropriate size. So now I have a game that runs in a screen about 10% larger than the actual screen, and no way of actually clicking "OK" to confirm a smaller screen size. There doesn't seem to be any way to tab to the OK button, or to click it "below-screen" -- the mouse stops at the screen bottom.

Is there a way to force a program or game to start at a certain resolution?

Answer (score 0):

While you can't drag up any higher with the title bar, have you tried holding Alt while dragging the window itself with the first mouse button? Some games and applications (VirtualBox in particular) will break this, but in general it should work.

If that doesn't work to allow you to drag the window higher so you can click OK, you 
will most likely have to use a command line option to the game, if it has one, or edit its configuration externally, if it stores that in a game.ini or similar somewhere. While it is possible to generically force most applications to a certain size with some tools such as `devilspie`, this doesn't generally work on games and such that may need to reload assets on resolution changes, or which require preserving an aspect ratio. Games do tend to have a config file, or a command line option, to specify the resolution to use, though.